# Sockjs reconnect attempt does not subscribe to RabbitMQ queue

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp, sockjs

I am facing a weird problem with connecting Rabbitmq from UI. I use 'xhr-polling' only due to some reason to connect rabbitmq queue from UI and it works fine for quite sometime when user lands on page but it disconnects with rabbitmq at some point without any error.

I have put in some logic to reconnect, once it is disconnected and as per the log it seems it connects but when I look at the RabbitMQ there is no client connected to it. However browser console (connected to server RabbitMQ/3.6.10) and keeps sending calling xhr_send?t=[random-key] and xhr?=[random-key] gets response 204 or 200  (As per developer tool).

When I refresh the whole page, it connects back again fine and see rabbitmq client queue as well something like (connected to server RabbitMQ/3.6.10).

Technology stacks are : Sockjs + Stompjs + RabbitMQ with Stomp plugin

So in summary reconnect logic shows it is connected but as per rabbitmq there is no subscribed client. Normally I see something like this stomp-subscription-rIUXo4Yvmilga2w3g5Lu6g as queue name when connected.

Comment: I can only recommend watching the connection with Wireshark to get a better understanding of exactly what is happening. The rabbitmq-users mailing list may be a good resource if you're able to provide code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I eliminated the use of Sockjs and started using native WebSocket class Also, I setup apache server to use wstunnel to connect RabbitMQ instance